# Split and remove duplicate from String

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to split the given string and remove the duplicate from that string. Like I have following string:

> This is my first post in stack overflow, I am very new in development and I did not have much more idea about the how to post the question.

Now I want to split that whole string with white space and that new array will did not have duplicate entry.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
"This is my first post in stack overflow, I am very new in development and I did not have much more idea about the how to post the question."
    .Split()                       // splits using all white space characters as delimiters
    .Where(x => x != string.Empty) // removes an empty string if present (caused by multiple spaces next to each other)
    .Distinct()                    // removes duplicates
```

`Distinct()` and `Where()` are LINQ extension methods, so you must have `using System.Linq;` in your source file.

The above code will return an instance of `IEnumerable<string>`. You should be able to perform most operations required using this. If you really need an array, you can append `.ToArray()` to the statement.

Comment: The Anti-Linq-Movement asks: Is there a simple linqless way?

Comment: Is it not simple enough? I don't like the fact that the extension methods exist in `System.Linq`. In themselves they have nothing to do with "Language-Integrated Query". They're just a bunch of extension methods for enumerable types.

Answer (score 3):

add the array into a `HashSet<String>`, this would remove the duplicates.
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) is Micorosft documentation on HashSet..

Answer (score -1):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string str = "abcdaefgheijklimnop";
        char[] charArr = str.ToCharArray();
        int lastIdx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length;)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < str.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (charArr[i] == charArr[j])
                {   
                    //Console.WriteLine(charArr[i]);   
                    int idx = i != 0 ? i - 1 : i;
                    lastIdx = j;
                    string temp = str.Substring(idx, j - idx);
                    Console.WriteLine(temp);
                    break;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(lastIdx));
```

}